# UIView not transparent on iOS device but is transparent on the simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, transparency

Have a view which I want to make transparent, it works on the simulator, but for some reason not on my device. I have no idea why this happens. My code looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

    [...]
    UIView *transparentBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

    // Doesn't work on my device. 
    transparentFlipBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // I have also tried. 
    // transparentFlipBackgroundView.alpha = 0;
    // transparentFlipBackgroundView.opaque = YES
    // transparentFlipBackgroundView.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

    // I later add the view to an array...
    self.pageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:transparentFlipBackgroundView, lastPage, nil];  
    [...]
}
```

Any ideas why this happens, and how should I make the UIView transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got another device you can try it on? If it works on the simulator, surely it should work on your device too? If you'd like, I wouldn't mind trying on one of my devices.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change

```
transparentFlipBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

to

```
transparentFlipBackgroundView.backgroundColor = 
                                      [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem with XCode5 and iOS7 SDK. I found that I had turned on "Increase Contrast" under the Accessibility settings (Settings/General/Accessibility). This caused the Navigation bar to be less transparent than it would be if this setting were turned OFF.

Turned it OFF and now I can see some transparency behind the bars. It's still not as much as the simulator, but it's better now.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty hacky solution,but I fixed it by making the view with CGRectZero.